# 'LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (run PHP-file with shell_exec)

Tags: command-line, php, php-cli, libxml

I wrote a PHP-script to execute another PHP-file in the terminal and got an error. If I run:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php -v 2>&1");
echo "<PRE>$output</PRE>";
```

then I get this message:

```
/usr/bin/php: /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2:
version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /usr/bin/php)
```

I tried to goolge it but the answers were too hard to understand for me, I'm quite new to all this.. Could somebody explain the problem or help me fix it? All I can understand is that I obviously got a wrong version of something.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `strings /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2 | grep LIBXML2_2.9.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your library version is too old. You need `libxml2 >=2.9.0`

For Trusty and newer install the package `libxml2`

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

remove the old library (backup)

```
mv /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2 /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2.bak
```

and create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 /opt/lampp/lib
```